# Direct way to get camera screenshot

Tags: python, image, opencv, webcam

I'm working with Python OpenCV to a project that as an initial step involves capturing an image from a webcam; I tried to automate this process by using `capture = cv2.VideoCapture` and `capture.read()`, but the camera's video mode activation and its subsequent self-adjusting are too slow for what I want to achieve in the end.

Is there a more direct method of automatically capturing a screenshot with Python (and OpenCV)? If not, do you have any alternative suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem but could not find any better solution.

Comment: If I understood correctly, what you currently do is initializing the video capture inside your screenshot function? (`capture = cv2.VideoCapture` then `capture.read()`)

Comment: Exactly, but I wanted to know if is there a more direct way to access to the camera frame, but I guess that initialization is a needed step.

Comment: @Eggman Camera's initialization takes time and need to done only once at the beginning of your program. Please see my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your camera screenshot function to be *responsive*, you need to initialize the *camera capture* **outside** of this function.

On the following code snippet, the `screenshot` function is triggered by pressing **c**:

```
import cv2

def screenshot():
    global cam
    cv2.imshow("screenshot", cam.read()[1]) # shows the screenshot directly
    #cv2.imwrite('screenshot.png',cam.read()[1]) # or saves it to disk

if __name__ == '__main__':

    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # initializes video capture

    while True:
        ret, img = cam.read()
        cv2.imshow("cameraFeed", img) # a window is needed as a context for key capturing (here, I display the camera feed, but there could be anything in the window)
        ch = cv2.waitKey(5)
        if ch == 27:
            break
        if ch == ord('c'): # calls screenshot function when 'c' is pressed
            screenshot()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**To clarify**: `cameraFeed` window is only here for the purpose of the demo (where `screenshot` is triggered manually). If `screenshot` is called automatically in your program, then you don't need this part.

Hope it helps!

Comment: "global" here is not needed as you are not changing the value for "cam"

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to do 3 things:

```
#init the cam
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#get a frame from cam
ret, frame = video_capture.read()
#write that to disk
cv2.imwrite('screenshot.png',frame)
```

of course, you should wait a while before, if not you could save a weird black screen (or just the 1st thing the camera got :-) )